# Authenticate using a different firestore instance

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

Can we have a database in firestore solely for authentication and have every website I create have a primary firestore instance for storing data and a secondary firestore instance to sign in and still force database/storage rules based on this auth?

[This blog talks about it but scopes to just google auth provider and asks me to use server side coding for email/password.](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html) Can anyone explain how?

Comment: Are you looking to use a single project for auth and a project for each of your websites?

Comment: The blog is talking about how to have multiple Firebase instances in your project, all pointing to different Firebase projects. This means that the users need to be authenticated on all the instances, each instance will have it's own rules. The part you mentioned for Google auth, is so you can use the same uid on each database to have data referenced to the same user. If you are using email and password, you will need to create custom tokens for each instance with the same uid, so you can have data for the same user (using the uid) on all the instances.

Comment: @JasonBerryman yes. you're right.